# Problema con matrices en python

Tags: python, bucles, matrices

Quiero obtener el promedio de una fila de matrices, como supuestamente las coordenadas de los números de la matriz son los pupitres de clase. Por ello si la fila que queremos solicitar es 0 o un número negativo la función debe devolver -1. Si el pupitre de un alumno aparece como 0 es que no ha asistido, y por ello no se le debe contar para calcular el promedio.
Al probar el código no entiendo porque no me funciona para las matrices, obtengo error antes de lo debido, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, gracias.

```
def promedo_fila(matriz:list, fila:int)->float:
    proemdio = 0
    suma = 0
    ausente = 0

    if fila <= 0:
        promedio = -1
    else:
        for columna in range(0,len(matriz[0])):
            if matriz[fila][columna] == 0:
                ausente += 1
                columna += 1
            
            else:    
                suma += matriz[fila][columna]
                columna += 1
        promedio = suma/(len(matriz[fila]-ausente))
    return promedio
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega un ejemplo con datos de entrada, salida y mostrar/explicar el resultado correcto.

Comment: Hola Salvador, para empezar quita los dos **columna += 1** que eso lo hace automáticamente el for.

Comment: El cero es redundante en `range(0, len(..` . Si el valor inicial es cero, lo puedes omitir y escribir solo el valor final `range(0,len(matriz[0]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lista = [ [ 10, 8, 9, 8 ], [ 6, 10, 7, 6 ], [ 1, 4, 5, 3 ] ]

def promedo_fila( matriz, fila ) -> float:
    promedio = 0
    suma = 0
    ausente = 0

    if fila <= 0:
        promedio = -1
    else:
        fila -= 1
        for columna in range( 0, len( matriz[0] )):
            if matriz[ fila ][ columna ] == 0:
                ausente += 1
            
            else:    
                suma += matriz[ fila ][ columna ]
        promedio = suma / ( len( matriz[fila] ) - ausente )

    return promedio   
    
print( promedo_fila( lista, 1 ))
```

Con unas pequeñas modificaciones a tu código llegamos a Roma.
Primero borramos **columna += 1** como te indiqué en los comentarios.
Dado que te piden la fila de forma natural, y los array no empiezan en "1" sino en "0", cuando entramos al **else** le restamos uno a **fila**.
Y por último, en **promedio = suma / ( len( matriz[fila] ) - ausente )** quitamos un paréntesis, que estaba sobrando.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Nota: los burros siempre en la última fila ;)

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo ya la respuesta de Marce Puente basada en el código original del OP, vengo a ofrecer está solución desde cero:

```
def promedio(matriz, fila):
    average = -1
    if 0 < fila < len(matriz[0]):
        notas = [x for x in matriz[fila - 1] if x]
        if notas:
            average = sum(notas) / len(notas)

    return average
```

Lo primero es inicializar el valor a retornar con -1, señalando un fallo. Con eso simplificamos el resto del código, pues ahora sólo necesitamos cambiarlo si todo es correcto.

```
average = -1
```

La función luego revisa que la fila vaya de 1 hasta el largo de la matriz. Si se cumple, usamos una comprensión de lista para obtener la lista `notas` con todas aquellas distintas de cero. Recuerda que `x` es `True` solo si es distinto de cero:

```
notas = [x for x in matriz[fila - 1] if x]
```

Para calcular el promedio basta sumar la lista y dividirla por el número de elementos, siempre que haya al menos uno. En Python una lista vacia es `False` cuando se evalúa en una expresión booleana. Si tiene elementos, es `True`:

```
if notas:
    average = sum(notas) / len(notas)
```

Como vez, así no necesitas llevar una cuenta separada de cuantas notas tienes realmente; Python lo hace por ti.

#### Demo

Te tome la libertad de copiar los datos de Marce Puente, agregando una fila de cero y ceros por las otras filas.

```
lista = [ [ 10, 8, 9, 0, 8 ], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 6, 10, 0, 7, 6 ], [ 1, 4, 0, 5, 3 ] ]

def promedio(matriz, fila):
    average = -1
    if 0 < fila < len(matriz[0]):
        notas = [x for x in matriz[fila - 1] if x]
        if notas:
            average = sum(notas) / len(notas)

    return average

for i in range(-1,10):
    print(f"Promedio fila {i} = {promedio(lista, i)}")
```

produce:

```
Promedio fila -1 = -1
Promedio fila 0 = -1
Promedio fila 1 = 8.75
Promedio fila 2 = -1
Promedio fila 3 = 7.25
Promedio fila 4 = 3.25
Promedio fila 5 = -1
Promedio fila 6 = -1
Promedio fila 7 = -1
Promedio fila 8 = -1
Promedio fila 9 = -1

Process finished with exit code 0
```